# Show that W is a vector space and exhibit a basis for W

Tags: linear-algebra

it is the first time I see an exercise like this and I really don't know where to start.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Let $P_3$ be the set of all the polynomials of degree at most 3.

Consider the vector space $V = P_3$ and consider the set
 W = { $f ∈ V :f(1) = 0$}.

Show that W is a vector space and exhibit a basis for W .

Finally, find another basis.

Comment: What is $P_3$? Is it a polynomial space? If so, are the coefficients integers, real, complex? Please elaborate.

Comment: $P_3$ is the set of all polynomial of degree at most 3. 
You are right sorry.

Comment: Are the poylnomial coefficients real?

Comment: Yes they are real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that $W \subseteq V$ so all that is left to show is that $W$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. I will assume that this is a vector space over $\mathbb R$ but this argument works for any field.

Let $f,g \in W$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ then $f(1)=0$ and $g(1)=0$, therefore $$(\alpha f+g)(1)=\alpha \underbrace {f(1)}_{=0}+\underbrace {g(1)}_{=0}=0$$ and so $W$ is closed under linear combinations of it's elements. It follows that $W$ is a subspace of $V$.

An arbitrary element $p \in V$ can be written as the linear combination $$p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$ where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$. From this we get a basis for $V$ to be $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$. Now suppose $p$ is in the subspace $W$, then $p(1)=a+b+c+d=0$, thus an arbitrary element of $W$ can be written as $$p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx-(a+b+c) = a(x^3-1)+b(x^2-1)+c(x-1)$$ for some $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$ which is a linear combination of the elements $\{ x^3-1,x^2-1,x-1\}$, so this is a basis of $W$. To find another basis you can simply take 3 linearly independent linear combinations of the above basis.

Comment: Thank you alex for your patience and your clear answer

Answer (score 1):

Any "polynomial of degree at most 3" can be written in the form $ax^3+ bx^2+ cx+ d$ where a, b, c, and d can be any numbers, includeing 0.  Saying that "f(1)= 0" means that $a(1^3)+ b(1^2)+ c(1)+ d= a+ b+ c+ d= 0$ or $d= -a- b- c$.  We can write such a polynomial as $ax^3+ bx^2+ cx+ (-a- b- c)= a(x^3- 1)+ b(x^2- 1)+ c(x- 1)$.  So one possible basis is $\{x^3- 1, x^2- x, x- 1\}$.

Of course $a+ b+ c+ d= 0$ can also be written as $a= -b- c- d$ so that we can write such a polynomial as $(-b- c- d)x^3+ bx^2+ cx+ d= b(x^2- x^3)+ c(x- x^3)+ d(1- x^3)$.  Another possible basis is $\{x^2- x^3, x- x^3, 1- x^3\}$

Answer (score 1):

If I well understand, $W$ is the subspace of polynomials $P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ such that $P(1)=0$. This means that the elements of $W$ are such that:
$$
a+b+c+d=0 \quad \iff \quad d=-a-b-c \qquad (1)
$$

For the first question:

if $p_1(x)=a_1x^3+b_1x^2+c_1x+d_1$ and $p_2(x)=a_2x^3+b_2x^2+c_2x+d_2$  are elements of $W$ such that $P_1(1)=P_2(1)=0$ than also $P_1(1)+kP_2(1)=0+k\cdot 0=0$, and this means that $W$ is a vector space.

For the second question, note that, from $(1)$, the elements of $W$ in the standard basis $\{x^3,x^2,x,1 \}$ of $P_3$ are expressed as the linear combination

$$P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx-a-b-c=ax^3-a+bx^2-b+cx-c=$$
$$=a(x^3-1)+b(x^2-1)+c(x-1)$$

so $\{x^3-1, x^2-1,x-1\}$ is a basis for $W$

I think that now you can find another basis.

Comment: Grazie professor Novati. Mi ha aiutato molto a capire